# Ionic - Image scale is not respected on some devices

Tags: css, ionic-framework, display

I made an app with Ionic framework and I have a problem on some devices.
This is my homepage : 
[image]

And on some devices (iPhone 5S, iPhone 5C, Samsung S5), the page is displayed like this :

[image]

This page is made with an ion-grid. 
Here is a part of my css :

```css
    ion-grid{
        height: 100%;

        ion-row.homeM{
            height: 20%;

            img{
                height: 80%;
            }
            p{
                margin-top: 0px;
            }
        }

        ion-row.homeML{
            height: 25%;

            img{
                height: 75%;
            }
            p{
                margin-top: 0px;
            }
        }
    }
```

ion-row.homeM is for portrait display and ion-row.homeML is for landscape display.

Help is welcome :) !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify a max-height in px, dpi, em or other unit?
This may be related to a resolution/space issue because of the percentage in the css.

Try something like:

```
ion-grid{
    height: 100%;

    ion-row.homeM{
        height: 80px;

        img{
            height: 60px;
        }
        p{
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
    }

    ion-row.homeML{
        height: 60px;

        img{
            height: 40px;
        }
        p{
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I put this on the ion-grid? I will try this

Comment: Try both and see what you get.  
Also try to change those values in both to see how much the display changes.  
You will certainly get it around that.

Answer (score 0):

To create Responsive design try using **"vh for height"** and **"vw for width"** or "em"
instead of **"px or %"**
soo try this:

```
 ion-grid{
 height:98vh;
  ion-row.homeM{
    height: 40vh;

    img{
        height: 100vh;
      /*you can add max-height to prevent img to be stretched*/
         max-height:100px;//for example
        width:30vw;
    }
    p{
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this help and you can know more about what I said From here :
 [ViewPort Unit](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)